# TYPO3 Elements - how can i make an element/extensionthat add div

Tags: typo3, fluid

In TYPO3 v.6.1 Fluid/Extbase i have a FLUID template with this code

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="inner-content">
        <f:format.raw>{content}</f:format.raw>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now i want to add some colums to the content, that use Class="spanxx".
So i need to make an extension so i can add the following.

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="inner-content">
        this is the left side     
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="inner-content">
        this is the right side     
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have 12 span's, and want to add 3,4,6,8,9,12 span's, in the ex. i have added to colums thats span = 6 (50%).

But how can i make an extension, that can do that - or is it easier just to make a FLUID template that have the spans i want.

Lets say i have 3 rows thats 12 colums width, then in the first i want 2 colums (2x6span) in the middle i want 2 colums (3span and 9span) and in the last one i want one column thats span all 12.

That can again be diffrent from page to page, thats why i dont make a FLUID Template, but ask "how to make an extension" so i can add the colums i want.

I know JF-multi content is a solution, but then i have a problem adding my span classes to the divs.

someone that have an idea to fix this og to do this.

Comment: Did you took a look at gridelements?

Comment: Hi pduersteler, no bc. im new to TYPO3 - but I will look at that extension, thx ;-)

Comment: pduersteler can u give me an "answer" the "gridelements" ext. i what im looking for.

Comment: As soon as I find time, I may, yes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether or not the backend user should be able to define the grid layout himself:

If he should just be able to choose one of the predefined layouts, you should create a number of predefined backend_layouts with accompanying Fluid templates. The TYPO3 documentation is a bit lacking here, but there is a helpful tutorial in a blog post: *[Implementing TYPO3's backend layouts](http://blog.sebastiaandejonge.com/articles/2012/july/26/implementing-typo3s-backend-layouts/)*.

If he should be able to define the grid himself, you're probably better of using one of the suggested extensions. Please be aware though, that the backend user is now in charge of determining the page layout. Depending on the project and its users, that might or might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [EXT:fluidcontent_bootstrap](https://github.com/NamelessCoder/fluidcontent_bootstrap) which provides some bootstrap functionality to the backend (more than the column definitions you were asking for).

Some might argue that this in combination with the required EXT:flux introduces XML in the database yet again and doesn't just work on the core, but to me flux and the related extensions have quite a good concept.